# Xamarin delete from listview+sqlite database

Tags: c#, sql, xamarin

Here i saw some similar question, but my some different. 
On app had some books categories, on clicked opening list of books

```
    public class CategoryItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewCategory" Margin="20" ItemSelected="OnListItemSelected">
...
  <ViewCell>
  ...
  <ImageButton Source="more.png" Pressed="OnDeleteClicked"/>
```

Here is method

```
        async void OnListItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //((App)App.Current).ResumeAtTodoId = (e.SelectedItem as TodoItem).ID;
        //Debug.WriteLine("setting ResumeAtTodoId = " + (e.SelectedItem as TodoItem).ID);
        if (e.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new BooksListPage
            {
                BindingContext = e.SelectedItem as CategoryItem
            });
        }
    }

    public async void OnDeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)            
    {
        var todoItem = (CategoryItem)BindingContext;
        await App.Database.DeleteCategoryAsync(todoItem);
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

CategoryItemDatabase

```
public Task<int> DeleteCategoryAsync(CategoryItem item)
    {
        return database.DeleteAsync(item);
    }
```

I added imagebutton to delete category on list, but got error:

```
"Cannot delete Object: it has no PK"
```

p.s.
sorry my bad english

Comment: where is the code for DeleteCategoryAsync?  Are you sure that todoItem has an ID set?

Comment: Ty for looking my question. I edited post and add code

Comment: BindingContext is the BindingContext of your page, not the individual item that you clicked on.  So your cast is probably failing and todoItem is probably null

Comment: <ImageButton Source="more.png" Pressed="OnDeleteClicked"/>  i was think, then listview created all imagebuttons binding to individual item. Can u please show me, how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

But if i going to CategoryPage editing from listview:

```
async void OnListItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new CategoryItemPage
        {
            BindingContext = e.SelectedItem as CategoryItem
        });
    }
}
```

And using button to delete

```
   var deleteButton = new Button { Text = "Delete" };
        deleteButton.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            var categoryItem = (CategoryItem)BindingContext;
            await App.Database.DeleteCategoryAsync(categoryItem);
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        };
```

Its working. But i want delete from listview